# How to force update of child components after parent got mounted

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I have the code:

```
<Text height={h}>
  <Paragraph />
  <Paragraph />
</text>
```

Initially `Text` has a height specified, but sometimes contents of `Paragraph`s can be lengthy and `Text` height to be increased to fit all the contents. Once a max value for height reached, then `Paragraph` font size should be set smaller by small steps until text fits entirely `Text`.

If texts overflow `Text` is available only in onMount step (`root.scrollHeight > h`). Adjusting `Text`'s height works fine, but how to force Svelte to update child components if max height value have reached?

Comment: Can you create example?

Comment: Text.svelte:
`<div bind:this={root}>
   <slot />
</div>


<script>
onMount(()=>{
  if(h < root.scrollHeight)
     h+= 10
})`

Comment: Have you tried to call tick on child component https://svelte.dev/tutorial/tick?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the solution is: `{#key aProp}`

Answer (score 1):

As noted by others, there are a few methods to force the DOM to update:

1. Svelte [`#key`](https://svelte.dev/docs/logic-blocks#key) causes the element (or component) and children to completely update when the prop changes

```html
{#key h}
  <Text height={h}>
    <Paragraph />
    <Paragraph />
  </text>
{/key}
```

2. You can alternately add a unique value (ever used this hack in a URI to load remote assets w/o caching?), below an example with [`#each`](https://svelte.dev/docs/logic-blocks#each)

```html
<Text height={h}>
  {#each collection as item (Math.random())}  
    <Paragraph />
  {/each}
</text>
```

Here's a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/a448b1b3d6564d378e854d5a19aa4246?version=4.2.8) showing both to reset inline styles.